# Batched write to Firebase Cloud Firestore failed due to wrong type

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to execute a batched write to my database. However there seems to be a problem with `data[]` because I get this error:

```
FirebaseError: Expected type 't', but it was: a custom e object
```

**The Code:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="setData()">
      Write to Firestore
    </v-btn>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import { db } from '@/firebase'

export default {
  methods: {
    setData() {
      
    var data = 
      [
        { 
          'title':'Ipsum lorem',
          'description':'Some text...',
          'color':'#03A9F4',
          'meta': 
            { 
              'docID':'',
              'createdBy':'', 
            }
        },
        { 
          'title':'Loren ipsum',
          'description':'Some more text...',
          'color':'#06A1F3',
          'meta': 
            { 
              'docID':'',
              'createdBy':'', 
            }
        }
      ]

      var batch = db.batch()
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        var dbRef = db.collection('teams').doc('team01').collection('templates')
        batch.set(dbRef, doc)
      })
      batch.commit().then(function() {
        return console.log("done")
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In my file `data[]` contains more objects than shown here. They are below the limit of 500. *This is done in my Vue.js app using Vuetify.*

1. **How can I solve this problem?**
2. **How can I add the id/reference of each document created and put it in `meta.docID`?** I can't get this to work with batched writes.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `dbRef` is a CollectionReference object:

```
var dbRef = db.collection('teams').doc('team01').collection('templates')
```

It's not valid to pass a CollectionReference to `set()`:

```
batch.set(dbRef, doc)   // this isn't valid
```

As you can see from the API documentation, [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#set) requires a DocumentReference as its first argument instead, so you will need to identify a document to write in order to call it.  This means you'll need to figure out a unique ID of a document to write here.  For example:

```
var dbRef = db
    .collection('teams')
    .doc('team01')
    .collection('templates')
    .doc("what-is-your-document-id?")
```

If you need a random document ID, you can simply provide no arguments in the call to `doc()`:

```
var dbRef = db
    .collection('teams')
    .doc('team01')
    .collection('templates')
    .doc()
```