# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Tc', but it was: an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Following the firebase v9 docs I am trying to implement the onSnapshot to listen to a document change but I keep getting this error.

> FirebaseError: Expected type 'Tc', but it was: an object

Here is some simple implementation:

```
const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const rooms = collection(db, 'rooms');
    const unsub = onSnapshot(rooms, (snapshot) => {
        setChannels(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data().name
        })))
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });

  }, []);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batched write to Firebase Cloud Firestore failed due to wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396267/batched-write-to-firebase-cloud-firestore-failed-due-to-wrong-type)

Comment: No it doesn't. All I am doing is passing args to the onSnapshot which is a collection ref and a callback to handle the data. I cant debug the error, whats 'Tc' and what am I passing as an object? @Danial